# The texture in my model breaks only when i try to render it

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm relatively new to blender, and i was trying to create a simple human model following a tutorial and making the textures myself, thing is, when i try to render it, the texture breaks, forming seams everywhere as depicted below
[image: A cropped photo of my model, completely black except for some details and depicting a seam in the leg]

Weird thing is that, when it just starts rendering the model, the texture looks fine, it's after the compositing (which adds the outline) that the texture breaks

[image: The same picture as before but without the outline, it shows the same part of the body but with a seamless texture]

I made sure there weren't any seams when i made the texture, i don't know what could be going wrong or how to fix it

Here's a picture of the nodes i used during compositing, i'm not sure if that has to do with anything since it's only job is to add the outline once it's done rendering

[image]

Comment: You said it happens after compositing and not before. So can you provide a screenshot of the compositing nodes?

Comment: My first guess is that the faces of the model are split, and somehow that is affecting the composite.